# flask `Base query` object isn't callable?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I'm working on a project. when I set up `flask-login` system after that I'm getting error.

**Error:**

> TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable

**when I remove `flask-login system`. It's working but I need to use.**

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return Login.query(user_id) # <<------------- Problem is here --------------->>
```

**If I use `Login.query(user_id)` instead `db.session.query(Login).filter_by(id=user_id)`.**

> AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'

I'd try to figure out what I'm doing wrong but still I don't know?

**Model.py**

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from run import db, date


class Login(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'login'
    id = db.Column('No', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column('Username', db.String(50), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column('Email', db.String(100), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column('Password', db.String(50), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column('Date', db.String(20), nullable=False, default=date)

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return True
    @property
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return True
    @property
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id
    @property
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Login(name=%s, email=%s, password=%s, date=%s)>' % (self.name, self.email, self.password, self.date)
```

**route.py**

```
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash
from model import Post, Contacts, Login_form, Signup_form, Login
from flask_login import login_required, login_user, current_user
from run import app, db, login_manager


# user id loader <<--------------- Problem is here 'flask-login query' ---------------------->>
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return Login.query(user_id)


@app.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    posts = db.session.query(Post).all()
    return render_template('index.html', posts=posts)

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/add_post')
@login_required
def add_posts():
    return render_template('add_post.html')

@app.route('/post')
@login_required
def post():
    all_post = db.session.query(Post).all()
    return render_template('post.html', posts=all_post)


@app.route('/contact', methods=['POST','GET'])
@login_required
def contact():
    if request.method=='POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        phone = request.form['phone']
        msg = request.form['message']
        contact_form = Contacts(naem=name, email=email, phone=phone, message=msg)
        db.session.add(contact_form)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else: return render_template('contact.html')

@app.route('/<int:no>/post')
@login_required
def post_direction(no):
    posts = db.session.query(Post).filter_by(id=no).first()
    return render_template('post.html', posts=posts)


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    log_in = Login_form()
    if log_in.validate_on_submit():
        if log_in.email.data !='' and log_in.password.data !='':
            check = db.session.query(Login).filter_by(email=log_in.email.data)
            if check and check.password == log_in.password.data:
                login_user(check, remember=log_in.remember.data)
                return redirect(request.args.get('next'), 'index')
            else:
                flash(u'Email and password not matching!', 'Invalid')
        else:
            flash(u'Invalid email1 and password!', 'Invalid')
    else:
        return render_template('login.html', Login_form=log_in)

@app.route('/signup', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def signup():
    return render_template('signup.html', Signup_form=Signup_form('/signup'))


# unauthorized handle
@login_manager.unauthorized_handler
def unauthorized():
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.errorhandler(404)
def error(e):
    return render_template('404.html')
```

**run.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap


app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', template_folder='template')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/flask'
upload_path = './static/img'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = upload_path
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super_secret'


db = SQLAlchemy(app)
admin = Admin(app, template_mode='bootstrap3')
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.init_app(app)



from route import *



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
.......
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get by id use:

```
Login.query.get(user_id)
```

`Login.query` is a shortcut to `db.session.query(Login)`, it's not callable.

See Flask-SQLAlchemy docs for:

- [Querying Records](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/#querying-records)
- [`flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery`](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery)

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: `AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'`

Comment: Look at my code. I'm using `flask-login` system.

Comment: From which line are you getting that error?

Comment: so I need to use `user_id` instead `Login`. If I use `Login` still I'm getting error too.

Comment: I have `query` problem with `flask-login manager`. Please look at my code.

Comment: How can I figure out this error?. I spend my 4 days to fix this error.

Comment: Please Help me.

Comment: Please edit the question with tracebacks for the errors you are getting.

Comment: Problem is that if I use `db.session.query(Login).filter_by(id=user_id')`. so I'm getting  this error `AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'`

Comment: If I use `Login.query(user_id)` so I'm getting error  `AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute`

Comment: I'm getting error through `flask-login` system.

Comment: I'd need to see the full error traceback and the line that is producing that error. Check here: https://realpython.com/python-traceback/

Comment: `db.session.query(Login).filter_by(id=user_id')` doesn't return a user, you need to add `db.session.query(Login).filter_by(id=user_id').first()`. Or use what I have in my answer: `Login.query.get(user_id)`. The **.get** is important, just like **.first**

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now It's working.

Comment: Happy to help, I hope you mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: yes, why not, I do.